# No se detecta el atributo checked de un input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo estos siguientes códigos:

```
function imprimirPregunta()
{   
    $(".panel-answers").empty();
    $(".p-question").html((cont + 1) + ".- " + preguntas[cont]["pregunta"]);
    
    for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        var respuesta = preguntas[cont]["respuesta" + i] == preguntas[cont]["correcto"] ? "correcto" : "incorrecto";
        
        var panel = $("<div class='panel-answer'><p>" + preguntas[cont]["respuesta" + i] + "</p>"
                       + "<input type='radio' name='ranswer' value='" + respuesta + "'></div>");
        
        $(".panel-answers").append(panel);
    }
    
    $(".panel-answer").on("click", function(){
        $("input[name=ranswer]").removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).children("input[name=ranswer]").attr("checked", "checked");
        $(".panel-answer").removeClass("seleccionar");
        $(this).addClass("seleccionar");
    }); 
}

function verificar()
{
    $("input[name=ranswer]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            alert($(this).val());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

En el evento `click` de `.panel-answer` tengo esta línea de código:

```
$("input[name=ranswer]").removeAttr("checked");
```

Y esto porque cuando se selecciona un **input radio** no se eliminan los `checked` de los demas radios y tengo entendido que esto debe hacerlo automáticamente porque todos los radios tienen el mismo valor en el `name`, porque no lo esta haciendo?? No tengo ni idea.

Y el problema viene que la compu sigue haciendo lo que quiere, porque cuando ejecuto la función **verificar** no detecta el atributo `checked` en ningun radio y se se fijan después de eliminar todos los `checked`, agrego el atributo `checked` a un elemento radio en especifico.

Si quito esa línea si detecta el atributo `checked` pero si la pongo no. Por que esta haciendo eso??

Answer (score 1):

En el código mostrado en la pregunta no hay errores. Tal vez están en otro lado y tratas de solucionarlo manipulando directamente el atributo `checked`, pero casi tengo la certeza de que, en vez de ayudar, va a complicar más tu trabajo.

Para este ejemplo solo hice cambios:

1. Crear variables para poder ejecutar
2. Agregando un botón de verificación y asignar evento clic
3. Verificar que se haya marcado una opción y mostrar el valor
4. Agregué un botón para desmarcar la opción seleccionada y volver a comenzar

```js
// Crear variables para probar
let preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: '¿Cuál es la respuesta?',
        respuesta1: 'Uno',
        respuesta2: 'Dos',
        respuesta3: 'Tres',
        respuesta4: 'Cuatro',
        correcto: 'Tres'
    },
    {
        pregunta: '¿Cuál es la segunda respuesta?',
        respuesta1: 'Cinco',
        respuesta2: 'Seis',
        respuesta3: 'Siete',
        respuesta4: 'Ocho',
        correcto: 'Seis'
    }
];
let cont = 0;

function imprimirPregunta()
{   
    $(".panel-answers").empty();
    $(".p-question").html((cont + 1) + ".- " + preguntas[cont]["pregunta"]);
    
    for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        var respuesta = preguntas[cont]["respuesta" + i] == preguntas[cont]["correcto"] ? "correcto" : "incorrecto";
        
        var panel = $("<div class='panel-answer'><p>" + preguntas[cont]["respuesta" + i] + "</p>"
                       + "<input type='radio' name='ranswer' value='" + respuesta + "'></div>");
        
        $(".panel-answers").append(panel);
    }
}

$('#verifica').on('click', e => {
    // ¿Se seleccionó una opción?
    if($("input[name=ranswer]:checked").length == 1) {
        // Mostrar valor de elemento marcado
        console.log('Se seleccionó: ' + $("input[name=ranswer]:checked").val());
        // Incrementar contador
        cont ++;
        // Avanzar solo si es posible
        if(cont < preguntas.length) {
            imprimirPregunta();
        } else {
            // No hay más preguntas
            $('#verifica').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Por favor selecciona una respuesta');
    }
});

// En caso de querer desmarcar, puedes usar esta función
$('#limpia').on('click', e => {
    if($("input[name=ranswer]:checked").length == 1) {
        // [0] hace referencia al elemento HTML en vez del objeto jQuery
        $("input[name=ranswer]:checked")[0].checked = false;
    }
});

// Mostrar pregunta al cargar página
imprimirPregunta();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-question"></div>
<div class="panel-answers"></div>
<button type="button" id="verifica">Verificar</button>
<button type="button" id="limpia">Limpiar</button>
```

Por otra parte, no es conveniente que marques la respuesta correcta, porque se puede ver fácilmente en el código fuente o inspector de la página. Deberías poner el valor correspondiente a cada respuesta y hacer las validaciones correspondientes en el servidor, nunca directamente en el navegador.

Comment: Que rapido, apenas iba a crear una respuesta xd, en fin, algo mas que añadir seria comentarle al `OP` el hecho de que en un `input radio` no puedes desmarcar una opcion una vez seleccionada, lo maximo que puedes hacer es seleccionar algun otro boton, y que ademas la unica forma de "resetear" por asi decirlo el estado de todos los radios es eliminando y volviendo a crear esos elementos, lo cual es una dudosa practica y no deberia hacerse.

Comment: @Riven, no me metí en esos detalles porque no parece querer resetear (que [sí se puede](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)). Voy a esperar a ver qué dice OP para ver si es necesario agregar algo al respecto. Gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Oh vaya, es cierto si se puede, pero esa es otra propuesta, la cual es resetear directamente todo el `form`.

Comment: @Riven, sí se puede cambiando el atributo `checked`, aunque no lo logré con jQuery, pero sí con el objeto HTMLElement... también creía que no era posible.

Comment: Bueno lo que estoy haciendo para poner la siguiente pregunta con sus respuestas, es eliminar los input radios que se pusieron anteriormente para agregar otros radios con las nuevas respuestas

Comment: Lo que requiero es que en el mismo evento click de un div se elimine el atributo checked de todos los radios y al radio del div sobre el que se ejecuto el evento se le agregue dicho atributo

Comment: @JorgeAlonso, acabo de editar la pregunta y funciona como esperas, sin tener que eliminar el atributo, porque se está trabajando con elementos nuevos cada vez.